Is there any way to get a mapping of old and new commit hashes after `git rebase`?
When using git rebase to rebase a chain of commits onto a new destination, is there any way to generate a mapping from the original commit hashes to new commit hashes when such a correspondence exists?
I realize that there is not necessarily a 1:1 mapping; some of the original commits could get squashed, and some completely new commits could be added during the rebase.  I'm not particularly concerned about how those would be reported.
I'd rather not rely on commit messages since those are ambiguous; they're not necessarily unique, and they could change during the course of rebasing.  I suppose that I could match commits based on author timestamps as a last resort.

Did you consider just logging before and after, with a custom format? If so, what made you rule it out?

Agreed. This can also be done a posteriori using the rebased branch tip and its reflog.

@RomainValeri How would that work if the commits are reordered by the rebase?

@YSC And it would be unambiguous, even if commits are reordered, added, or removed?  If so, could you provide a more concrete example of how to extract that from the reflog?

No, I meant that these two lists could be the material for your mappings, but it's not a mapping per se since, as you already acknowledged it, there is no unambiguous mapping strategy here.

But I also do like @YSC's suggestion based on reflog. Depending on the expected results, it might be worth considering.

Nope. The reflogs are just history on past references. There are no tool to generally map commits to commits after a rebase. You have to do it yourself and set the limit on what the tool can accept yourself.

@RomainValeri I'm not following what I'd do with the lists other than to, say, compare the author timestamps, which I've already acknowledged would be my fallback plan if there isn't a better approach.

@YSC Well what I was ideally hoping for was that there's some way to tell git rebase to report that information directly.  I don't see any obvious command-line options to do it, --verbose  unfortunately doesn't do it.  Alas.

@jamesdlin What about using git cherry-pick instead of git rebase? git cherry-pick -x preserves the picked commit ID.

Ok found it! But it relies on an undocumented implementation detail of the post-rewrite hook, and might break anytime you upgrade git.
This mapping does exist but is deleted after the rebase is done. Ask git to save it with:
$ git rebase -x 'cp .git/rebase-merge/rewritten-list .' YOUR_REBASE_OPTIONS
Executing: cp .git/rebase-merge/rewritten-list .
Executing: cp .git/rebase-merge/rewritten-list .
Executing: cp .git/rebase-merge/rewritten-list .
Executing: cp .git/rebase-merge/rewritten-list .
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature/to-be-rebased.

Your mapping is saved in rewritten-list:
$ cat rewritten-list                                                                                                         
3fb5526b1cad6b25f88de7341df1a40950fbe350 78529c15f1b6311442103e852d7a95e436ac69ba
e5064eb78bde58d0158cdaffcd959e58e14b7d7a dd7cba3b2684df533cb7fe679860f3ed6b63607f
ab5747c8742deaad35bfdbef0de424b0b269cb52 face7f2dc24f5042d978240e6439cd3b51c55f4c
4a1f9285d71fca3323ea9d722da463b9b2ae8f0a 01009290a482c65c6faee07e70110f8f5f83e578


History before:
* 4a1f928 (HEAD -> feature/to-be-rebased) Wed Sep 18 10:13:42 CEST 2024
* ab5747c Wed Sep 18 10:13:41 CEST 2024
* e5064eb Wed Sep 18 10:13:40 CEST 2024
* 3fb5526 Wed Sep 18 10:13:39 CEST 2024
| * 83433bb (master) Wed Sep 18 10:13:01 CEST 2024
| * b6f51f5 Wed Sep 18 10:13:00 CEST 2024
|/
* c1e1324 Wed Sep 18 10:12:58 CEST 2024
* 95e8bf9 Wed Sep 18 10:12:20 CEST 2024

History after:
* 0100929 (HEAD -> feature/to-be-rebased) Wed Sep 18 10:13:42 CEST 2024
* face7f2 Wed Sep 18 10:13:41 CEST 2024
* dd7cba3 Wed Sep 18 10:13:40 CEST 2024
* 78529c1 Wed Sep 18 10:13:39 CEST 2024
* 83433bb (master) Wed Sep 18 10:13:01 CEST 2024
* b6f51f5 Wed Sep 18 10:13:00 CEST 2024
* c1e1324 Wed Sep 18 10:12:58 CEST 2024
* 95e8bf9 Wed Sep 18 10:12:20 CEST 2024


Note that this relies on an undocumented implementation detail of the post-rewrite hook. +1 in any case.

Noted, thank you for this useful information.

You can generate a mapping from the newest commit to the old commits
using the post-rewrite hook.
This is what I use:[1]
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Append the old hash to the notes for the new ref
# The note may contain multiple lines (git-rebase; squash and fixup)

while read line ; do
    read -a arr <<< "$line"
    # It seems that sometimes this is empty for some reason
    if [ "${arr[0]}" ]; then
        git notes --ref=previous-commits append \
            --no-separator -m"${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}"
    fi
done

post-rewrite gives you the hashes of the previous commits (one commit
in case of an amend, possibly multiple for a rebase due to the squash
operation).
This script adds the hashes to a Git Note named previous-commits.  Now
you can view the commits with git log --notes=previous-commits.
I also have a Git Notes rewrite rule which carries over this note to all
new commits caused by a rewrite operation (for all rewrite operations
that this hooks supports[2]):
[notes]
    rewriteRef = refs/notes/previous-commits

Which means that you should get a transitive mapping for each new
commit.
Reverse mapping
It should be possible to generate a reverse mapping: from old to
new. The raw data is there now.
Bugs?

These notes can get seriously big for me. Which doesn’t track with
many rewrite operations there have been. I’ve had to manually cull a
lot of lines a few times. There must be a bug in the script.

I will try to update this answer if I improve this procedure!
Notes

This requires a decently new version of Git due to the
--no-separator option (I’m currently on git version 2.46.0).
See man githooks; this hook currently only supports git commit --amend and git-rebase(1).  One can easily be surprised when doing
some other rewrite operation or “copy change” operation (git
cherry-pick(1)) when this hook has no effect.  So beware of that.

